# Select N random elements from a List efficiently (without toArray and change the list)

Tags: java, algorithm, random

As in the title, I want to use Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to select N random elements from a List but without using List.toArray and change the list. Here is my current code:

```
public List<E> getNElements(List<E> list, Integer n) {
    List<E> rtn = null;

    if (list != null && n != null && n > 0) {
        int lSize = list.size();
        if (lSize > n) {
            rtn = new ArrayList<E>(n);
            E[] es = (E[]) list.toArray();
            //Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm 
            for (int i = es.length - 1; i > es.length - n - 1; i--) {
                int iRand = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
                E eRand = es[iRand];
                es[iRand] = es[i];
                //This is not necessary here as we do not really need the final shuffle result.
                //es[i] = eRand;
                rtn.add(eRand);
            }

        } else if (lSize == n) {
            rtn = new ArrayList<E>(n);
            rtn.addAll(list);
        } else {
            log("list.size < nSub! ", lSize, n);
        }
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

It uses list.toArray() to make a new array to avoid modifying the original list. However, my problem now is that my list could be very big, can have 1 million elements. Then list.toArray() is too slow. And my n could range from 1 to 1 million. When n is small (say 2), the function is very in-efficient as it still need to do list.toArray() for a list of 1 million elements.

Can someone help improve the above code to make it more efficient when dealing with large lists. Thanks.

Here I assume Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle is the best algorithm to do the job of selecting n random elements from a list. Am I right? I would be very glad to if there is other algorithms better than Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle to do the job in terms of the speed and the quality of the results (guarantee real randomness).

**Update:**

Here is some of my test results:

When selection n from 1000000 elements.

When n<1000000/4 the fastest way to through using Daniel Lemire's Bitmap function to select n random id first then get the elements with these ids:

```
public List<E> getNElementsBitSet(List<E> list, int n) {
        List<E> rtn = new ArrayList<E>(n);
        int[] ids = genNBitSet(n, 0, list.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            rtn.add(list.get(ids[i]));
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

The genNBitSet is using the code generateUniformBitmap from https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2013/08/14/java/UniformDistinct.java

When n>1000000/4 the Reservoir Sampling method is faster.

So I have built a function to combine these two methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [**Resorvoir Sampling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Start with an initial array with first `k` elements, and modify it with new elements with decreasing probabilities:

java like pseudo code:

```
E[] r = new E[k]; //not really, cannot create an array of generic type, but just pseudo code
int i = 0;
for (E e : list) {
   //assign first k elements:
   if (i < k) { r[i++] = e; continue; }
   //add current element with decreasing probability:
   j = random(i++) + 1; //a number from 1 to i inclusive
   if (j <= k) r[j] = e;
}
return r;
```

This requires a single pass on the data, with very cheap ops every iteration, and the space consumption is linear with the required output size.

Comment: Resorvoir Sampling seems to be slower than BitSet here: http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2013/08/16/picking-n-distinct-numbers-at-random-how-to-do-it-fast/ Daniel Lemire's post is about selection N random number. Mine is about choosing N random elements from a List. I just wonder if Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle can deal my problem faster than BitSet.

Comment: @Leo That's comparing apples with oranges. If k = cn for some large enough constant c, resorvoir sampling will be more efficient. For small k, an O(k) w.h.p algorithm like the one described on that blog or in the other answer is obviously better

Comment: @NiklasB. Do u think, the Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle can performance better than  Resorvoir Sampling?  Resorvoir Sampling is one pass, but Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle can do 1/3 or 1/2 pass to get the expected random elements. It should need some additional data structures to keep record about which element is swapped to avoid changing the original list.

Answer (score 5):

If n is very small compared to the length of the list, take an empty set of ints and keep adding a random index until the set has the right size.

If n is comparable to the length of the list, do the same, but then return items in the list that don't have indexes in the set.

In the middle ground, you can iterate through the list, and randomly select items based on how many items you've seen, and how many items you've already returned. In pseudo-code, if you want k items from N:

```
for i = 0 to N-1
    if random(N-i) < k
        add item[i] to the result
        k -= 1
    end
end
```

Here random(x) returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and x (exclusive).

This produces a uniformly random sample of k elements. You could also consider making an iterator to avoid building the results list to save memory, assuming the list is unchanged as you're iterating over it.

By profiling, you can determine the transition point where it makes sense to switch from the naive set-building method to the iteration method.

Comment: Will the middle ground code select exactly k items?

Comment: I agree that it is difficult to find a "nice" solution for all cases - including the cases where 'n' is very small **or** very large compared to the list size. The first solution is simple, but it is also not entirely correct: You can not prove that this program will ever terminate. For a list with 100 elements, it might randomly put element 42 into the set. Then it might randomly put element 42 into the set. Then ... again. Forever. (Seems like a rather theoretical issue, but should be kept in mind)

Comment: @Leo This solution gives a set of exactly `k` items, assuming you use a valid set implementation for `result`. Note however, performance is dependent on the concrete implementation of `list`, a LinkedList will suffer from poor performance, since it does not support an efficient `get(i)`

Comment: @Marco13 It's a [Las Vegas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm) algorithm. For small k, the runtime is "small" with high probability

Comment: @Marco13 There is a very nice solution, actually (added answer)... Also, the algorithm will always terminate, the probability of having a vector with a constant suffix, is 0 - so with probability 1, it will terminate.

Comment: @amit You can iterate through the list simultaneously with `i` if you have a linked list.

Comment: @NiklasB. I deleted the last comment, I had a mistake, I'll revisit it later. The probability to generate a non-terminating sequence is in the same scale of the probability to get a specific number in R from `[0,1]` with uniform random distribution. (assuming real random generator). It could happen on paper, but for all aspects of it, it really cannot happen, and even if you run an infinite test that generates this experiment, you won't ever get it, with p~=1 (since the  test sequence is [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set), while the problem space isn't)

Comment: @amit Well let's forget about that, in any case, termination is very very very likely, which is the key point here

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that you can generate n random indices out of m that are pairwise disjoint and then look them up efficiently in the collection. If you don't need the order of the elements to be random, then you can use an algorithm due to Robert Floyd.

```
Random r = new Random();
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int j = m - n; j < m; j++) {
    int t = r.nextInt(j);
    s.add(s.contains(t) ? j : t);
}
```

If you do need the order to be random, then you can run Fisher--Yates where, instead of using an array, you use a `HashMap` that stores only those mappings where the key and the value are distinct. Assuming that hashing is constant time, both of these algorithms are asymptotically optimal (though clearly, if you want to randomly sample most of the array, then there are data structures with better constants).

Answer (score 2):

Just for convenience: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an implementation of the [Resorvoir Sampling proposed by amit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23720942/3182664) (**possible upvotes should go to him** (I'm just hacking some code))

It seems like this is indeed a algorithm that nicely covers the cases of where the number of elements to select is *low* compared to the list size, **and** the cases where the number of elements is *high* compared to the list size (assumung that the properties about the randomness of the result that are stated on the wikipedia page are correct).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ReservoirSampling
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        example();
        //test();
    }

    private static void test()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");
        list.add("E");
        int size = 2;

        int runs = 100000;
        Map<String, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<runs; i++)
        {
            List<String> sample = sample(list, size);
            String s = createString(sample);
            Integer count = counts.get(s);
            if (count == null)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            counts.put(s, count+1);
        }
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static String createString(List<String> list)
    {
        Collections.sort(list);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : list)
        {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void example()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            list.add(String.valueOf((char)('A'+i)));
        }

        for (int i=1; i<=26; i++)
        {
            printExample(list, i);
        }
    }
    private static <T> void printExample(List<T> list, int size)
    {
        System.out.printf("%3d elements: "+sample(list, size)+"\n", size);
    }

    private static final Random random = new Random(0);
    private static <T> List<T> sample(List<T> list, int size)
    {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(Collections.nCopies(size, (T) null));
        int i = 0;
        for (T element : list)
        {
            if (i < size)
            {
                result.set(i, element);
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            i++;
            int j = random.nextInt(i);
            if (j < size)
            {
                result.set(j, element);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: FWIW if you don't want to take credit, you could make your answer a community wiki

Comment: @NiklasB Good idea, just changed it to a wiki answer

Comment: He. Thanks for the code. I have checked it. But its random quality is not high. I use the code from https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2013/08/14/java/UniformDistinct.java for the  Resorvoir Sampling and its random quality is very high.

Comment: I have serious tested. I use it to select 2 number from 1,2,3,4,5. And your code can not get the combo: "12" or "21". And the probability of having different combs are different. While in the code I linked, the probability of selecting different combos are the same. I did not try to find why. But if you are interested, you might want to have a look at the linked.

Comment: Daniel Lemire's Reservoir Sampling:|12.0,.1025|13.0,.0989|14.0,.0991|15.0,.0998|23.0,.1004|24.0,.1007|25.0,.1014|34.0,.0982|35.0,.0984|45.0,.1006|
Marco13's code Reservoir Sampling |13.0,.0837|14.0,.0823|15.0,.0837|23.0,.084|24.0,.0837|25.0,.0845|34.0,.1661|35.0,.1657|45.0,.1662

Comment: @Leo Indeed, two lines had been swapped (amit used 1-based indexing). I updated the sample and added a test that shows that the frequency of all combinations is now "as equal as it should be".

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is way smaller then size, you could use this algorith, witch is unfortunatly quadratic with `n`, but doest depend on size of array at all.

Example with size = 100 and `n` = 4.

```
choose random number from 0 to 99, lets say 42, and add it to result.
choose random number from 0 to 98, lets say 39, and add it to result.
choose random number from 0 to 97, lets say 41, but since 41 is bigger or equal than 39, increment it by 1, so you have 42, but that is bigger then equal than 42, so you have 43.
...
```

Shortly, you choose from remaining numbers and then compuce what number have you acctualy chosen. I would use link list for this, but maybe there are better data structures.

Comment: If I understood this correcly, this will cause the result to be *not* really random, because it will have a higher probability of *consecutive* numbers appearing in the result. (But the description is a bit vague, so I'm not sure)

Comment: I don't think so, in each step, it chooses uniformly random number from those not chosen yet. But the description sucks, i know :)

Answer (score 0):

*Summarizing Changwang's update.* If you want more than 250,000 items, use amit's answer. Otherwise use [`Knuth-Fisher-Yates Shuffle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) as shown in entirety here

> **NOTE**: The result is always in the original order as well

```
public static <T> List<T> getNRandomElements(int n, List<T> list) {
    List<T> subList = new ArrayList<>(n);
    int[] ids = generateUniformBitmap(n, list.size());
    for (int id : ids) {
        subList.add(list.get(id));
    }
    return subList;
}

// https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/2013/08/14/java/UniformDistinct.java
private static int[] generateUniformBitmap(int num, int max) {
    if (num > max) {
        DebugUtil.e("Can't generate n ints");
    }
    int[] ans = new int[num];
    if (num == max) {
        for (int k = 0; k < num; ++k) {
            ans[k] = k;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(max);
    int cardinality = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    while (cardinality < num) {
        int v = random.nextInt(max);
        if (!bs.get(v)) {
            bs.set(v);
            cardinality += 1;
        }
    }
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
        ans[pos] = i;
        pos += 1;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

If you want them randomized, I use:

```
public static <T> List<T> getNRandomShuffledElements(int n, List<T> list) {
    List<T> randomElements = getNRandomElements(n, list);
    Collections.shuffle(randomElements);
    return randomElements;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something for this in C#, here's my solution which works on a generic List.

It selects N random elements of the list and places them at the front of the list.

So upon returning, the first N elements of the list are randomly selected. It is fast and efficient even when you're dealing with a very large number of elements.

```
static void SelectRandom<T>(List<T> list, int n)
{
    if (n >= list.Count)
    {
        // n should be less than list.Count
        return;
    }
    int max = list.Count;
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int r = random.Next(max);
        max = max - 1;
        int irand = i + r;
        if (i != irand)
        {
            T rand = list[irand];
            list[irand] = list[i];
            list[i] = rand;
        }
    }
}
```